# Insert latitude and longitude from Python mysql.connector into MySQL using Tweepy

Tags: python, mysql, twitter, geolocation, tweepy

I'm attempting to use the Twitter Streaming API to put some Tweet objects from geo-encoded Tweets into columns in a MySQL database. Everything was going okay, but I somehow can't get the latitude and coordinates into the databse.

Here is my code:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import json
import datetime

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='twitterdb',
                              charset = 'utf8mb4')
cursor=cnx.cursor()

ckey=""
csecret=""
atoken=""
asecret=""

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):

        if status.coordinates is not None:
          created_at = status.created_at
          username = status.user.screen_name
          tweet = str(status.text)
          long = str(status.coordinates['coordinates'][0])  
          lat = str(status.coordinates['coordinates'][1])

        else:
            return

        print((str(created_at),ascii(username),ascii(tweet),long,lat))

        cursor.execute("INSERT into tweettablegeo (created_at, username, tweet, long, lat) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(created_at, username, tweet, long, lat))

        cnx.commit()
        return

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(locations=[-180,-90,180,90], stall_warnings = True)
```

I'm getting the error 
`"mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long, lat) VALUES ("`.

If I comment out the `cursor.execute` and `cnx.commit` lines, everything prints out to the console just fine.

I don't really have any coding background so thanks for any insight you can give me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`long` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in MySQL. To use it as a column name in a query you must quote it:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT into tweettablegeo (created_at, username, tweet, "
               "`long`, lat) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", 
               (created_at, username, tweet, long, lat))
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it!